# Where is NSReadPixel in MonoMac?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, monomac, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to find `NSReadPixel`. Seems like it comes from AppKit, but I can't find it in MonoMac.
Can someone tell me if it's implemented?

EDIT: I had to pinvoke it. The declaration is below.

Answer (score 1):

It is not implemented. So here's the PInvoke:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
extern static IntPtr NSReadPixel(System.Drawing.PointF point);
```

Example:

```
var color = new NSColor(NSReadPixel(aPoint)); // where aPoint is PointF
```